# How to use pandas data frame in my SQ query?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, dataframe, presto

I have a pandas dataframe: df. I got it with sql query. Now, I want to write another sql query that gets data from that pandas dataframe:

```
SELECT id, type, value
FROM df
GROUP BY id, type
```

I want to do that because first query is very big and second might get very big as well, so to avoid to large query, how to insert pandas dataframe into second query?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) is what you're looking for.